# Scan XML file for open tags

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I was trying to find out how to search/scan and xml document to find a custom tag that I made

for example, if I am looking for the beginning tage ("**{[::**") and ending tags (" **::]}**") and trying to get the xpath information value

```
  <Session>
<!--<add key="AuthStore" value="Database" />-->
<!--<add key="DataStore" value="Database" />-->
<!--<add key="NameStore" value="Database" />-->
<add key="DSN" value="{[::/configration/Session/DSN::]}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to accomplish, but the following XPath (2.0):

```
//(text()|@*)[contains(.,'{[::')][contains(.,'::]}')]/substring-before(substring-after(.,'{[::'),'::]}')
```

will return any text or attribute value that contains `{[::` and `::]}`.

For example, the above XPath used on this XML:

```
<add key="DSN" value="{[::/configration/Session/DSN::]}">
  <test>{[::/another/path::]}</test>
</add>
```

will return:

```
/configration/Session/DSN
/another/path
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're very welcome. Thanks for accepting my answer. +1 for a good question.

Comment: NP...will let you know if I need anything else regrading these parameters. AWESOME!